# NoMethodError in localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, localhost

I've been using rails server to preview some html/css changes I make into a website code shared on gh to me, but I can't access some pages because I get this error:

NoMethodError at /media
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClas

It is a page from a function in the users profile; I made a fake user in the terminal so I can access the profile page, but the one I want inside profile, gives that error.

This is the portion of code swowing:

```
  <div class="select_wrapper">

      <select name="trienal_id" id="" required>

      <option value="" disabled>Trienal</option>

      **<% Subject.where(discipline_type: 0)[1..3].each do |s| %>**

            <option value="<%= s.id %>" <%= "selected" if @tri_id==s.id %>><%= s.name %></option>

            <% end %>

       </select>

 </div>
```

Comment: You mentioned you made a fake user. Do you need to make fake Subjects too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in irb `($ irb)`

```
> x = []
> x[0]
=> nil
> x[1]
=> nil
```

So most likely your query `Subject.where(discipline_type: 0)` is returning `blank array []` which is followed by `[1..3]` result is `nil` followed by `each` which will result in `undefined method each for nil:NilClas`

You should use [limit](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/limit) function (Which specifies a limit for the number of records to retrieve)
e.g.

```
Subject.where(discipline_type: 0).limit(3)
```

So your code should look like

```
<% Subject.where(discipline_type: 0).limit(3).each do |s| %>
  <option value="<%= s.id %>" <%= "selected" if @tri_id==s.id %>><%= s.name %></option>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Subject.where` is likely returning less records than what your range index has specified. Not sure why you have the `[1..3]` in there. Use an each on your Subject.where, and add to the where clause if you need to limit it more based on criteria.

```
<% Subject.where(discipline_type: 0).each do |s| %>
   <!-- your code here -->
<% end %>
```